# Rails error when trying to install mysql client gem on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-connection

I already have a mysql server setup via MAMP.

But when trying to install the mysql Rails client (gem install mysql2) I get the following error:

> ```
>    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>     /Users/krisgandhi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
>     checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
>     checking for main() in -lm... yes
>     checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
>     checking for main() in -lz... yes
>     checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
>     checking for main() in -lsocket... no
>     checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
>     checking for main() in -lnsl... no
>     checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
>     checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
>     checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
>     *** extconf.rb failed ***
>     Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.
> ```

Comment: you may post your mkmf.log file to let others know more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should remove mysql from MAMP. And try:

```
brew install mysql
```

Or alternatively install from here, find a suitable dmg:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Comment: Thanks. The 'brew install mysql' fixed the error I was getting upon trying to install the rails mysql client using 'gem install mysql2' and also let me continue using the MAMP instance of mysql server.

I should mention that for the rails client to connect to my MAMP mysql instance I had to add a 'socket: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' entry to my database.yml config.